# Only first step with multi step registration

Tags: 7, forms, users

I'm using the module [Multi-step Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) for my user accounts. I have six steps in my registration proces.

But now I want to show only the **FIRST** step when a user registers. So the user can register with only username and email. And when they receive an email to set their password they can edit all their settings, all the steps with a wizard (this is also multi-step with the same module).

But I have no idea to make sure that when they register you can only see the first step...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make visible for specific fields in the Registration form for First Step, i.e., In Account Settings -> Edit the field which you do not require in first step just Uncheck "Display on user registration form". After successfully created an Account then in  Edit mode all the fields will appear. This is just my think not the exact answer.